# Windows 7 desktop background slide show

Tags: windows-7

I choose changing desktop background every day. What that means? When I turn on my computer next day, desktop background was same. I choose folder with 20 pictures. But I can change background manually by clicking right click on the desktop and then "next desktop background". I have 32 bit Win 7 Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you choose slide show as your wallpaper and put your PC in **Power saver mode** windows stops it to save battery power.

So the only way to play slide show is to turn on another power plan by going to `Control Panel > Power Options` and choose another option instead of Power saver.

hope it works.

Comment: I noticed that i have checked "when using battery power stop slide show". But I don't have battery in my laptop. I remove it before one month.

Comment: if you are not using battery, it's a hardware issue. but software obey its default-ordered process and you have to turn another plan on. also note that disabling the check box wont apply on **Power saver** status. it only works on custom defined Power Plans.

Comment: How I can resolve this isuue?

Comment: Actually U can define a custom power plan and set `Desktop Background Settings Slide Show: Available` or use another one. in this case i recommend u to select `Balanced` mode or `High Performance` cause you don't have battery also.